# Equivalent Metric Using Clopen Sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Prove that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $C$ and $X \setminus C$ are nonempty clopen sets, then there is an equivalent metric $\rho$ on $X$ such that $\forall a \in C, \quad \forall b \in X \setminus C, \quad \rho(a,b) \geq 1$.

I know the term "clopen" is not a very formal definition, at least not to my knowledge, but it does describe the two properties of the given sets: they are both open and closed.

Would I have to show that the metric $\rho$ satisfies the properties of a metric or would I need to show that the metric $d$ and the metric $\rho$ generate the same topology to show they are equivalent?

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated as I do not know where to begin or how to proceed in writing up a correct proof.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: "I know the term "clopen" is not a very formal definition" -- It's perfectly precise. A set is clopen if it's both open and closed. A set is closed if its complement is open. In the reals, only the empty set and the reals are clopen. In the discrete topology (every set is open) every set is clopen. It's an ugly word which is why a lot of people don't like it; but its meaning is standard.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval, Thanks for pointing that out, I will edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two metrics are said to be equivalent if they generate the same topology. This should answer the question in the third paragraph.

In order to find the desired equivalent metric $\rho$, try to leave the distance between any two points in $C$ as it is. The distance between any two points in $X\setminus C$ should remain the same too. Change only the distances between pairs of points in $C\times (X\setminus C)$.

**More details**: Define a function $\rho:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}_+$ as follows. Let $x,y\in X$. If both $x$ and $y$ lie in $C$, or both lie in $X\setminus C$, set $\rho(x,y)=d(x,y)$. Otherwise, set $\rho(x,y)=d(x,y)+100$. Show that $\rho$ is a metric. Show it is equivalent to $d$. Show it satisfies the desired property (this is the easiest part).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. If we do leave the distance between any two points, say $a, x \in C$, the same and similar for $b, y \in X \setminus C$, then isn't $C \times (X \setminus C)$ defined as $(a,b): a \in C, \quad b \in X \setminus C$? I am sorry, but I am still having difficulties in seeing this clearly. Thank you again for your patience.

Comment: @Jamil_V Please read what I added.